# Query Filtering by Year

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I’m new to `SQL` and learning on the hoof, I’m not good at reading books so like to ask questions to get me there step by step. Sorry the full query is not here as I left my laptop on my desk but I’m hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I need to add a **year filter** to the below so I can use it in `SSRS` but every time I change something it still reports 2018 date . Any help greatly appreciated

```
DECLARE @year date
SET @year = '20170101' --GETDATE()

--guarantee @year is Jan 01 00:00:00.
SET @year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT        Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 00, @year) AND 
                            SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, 01, @year) 
                       THEN SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
              SUM(CASE WHEN SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 01, @year) AND 
                            SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, 02, @year) 
                       THEN SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
              SUM(CASE WHEN SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 02, @year) AND 
                            SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, 03, @year) 
                       THEN SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Mar ,
              --...
              SUM(CASE WHEN SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 10, @year) AND 
                            SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, 11, @year) 
                       THEN SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
              SUM(CASE WHEN SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 11, @year) AND 
                            SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, 12, @year) 
                       THEN SalesInvoiceItems.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Dec

FROM            SalesInvoices INNER JOIN
                             SalesInvoiceItems ON SalesInvoices.SalesInvoice = SalesInvoiceItems.SalesInvoice INNER JOIN
                             Products ON SalesInvoiceItems.Product = Products.Product

    GROUP BY      Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription
    --ORDER BY      ...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add tag for the specific DB you are using to get attention from specific dev community..like Oracle / SQL Server

Comment: Doesn't `SET @year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` always return Jan 1, 2018?  What are you changing?

Comment: I would argue it's better to just have `SalesInvoices.EffectiveDate` as an output column and do the pivoting by month in SSRS. It will make your query MICH simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You set the year back to 2018 by using `GETDATE()` here:

```
SET @year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Change that to use your `@year` date instead:

```
DECLARE @year date = '20170101'
SET @year = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @year), 0)
```

Comment: Brilliant advice and I have it all working in SSMS but I'm struggling with the Parameters In SSRS as this does not appear to allow DECLARED values . I'm ok with Date range parameters in SSRS but this YEAR thing is new to me

Comment: @Bob Gotcha - For SSRS I believe you could just remove all the declare/set logic and define the parameter (ie `year = 20170101`) when you run the report, no?

Answer (score 0):

You are never too new to adopt good habits (yes, I know, these are a matter of opinion).  One such habit is to structure date range queries like this:

```
where yourDateField >= @theStartOfYourDateRange
and yourDateField < the day after @theEndOfYourDateRange
```

Among other things, if your date field is actually a datetime field, the time portion gets taken care of.  Also, your queries will run faster because you won't be filtering by function results.

The detail that will differ query to query will be the way that you declare the start and end date variables.  For this, you don't necessarily need to use sql.  If application code (.net, php, coldfusion, etc) is available, it might be easier to use that.

Comment: . I'm ok with Date range parameters in SSRS but this YEAR thing is new to me – Bob just now   edit